# regex filter column text in MSSQL Server 2005

Tags: sql-server, regex

I have a table that has a user agent field that I want to manipulate not filter. I want something like:

`select col_a, col_b, regex("/ompatible;/.+[ ;]/", col_c) from table;`

Is this even possible in MSSQL Server?

Comment: You could post some example rows. Maybe we could improve your already found solution.

Answer (score 0):

It seems it's not possible other than installing new stuff or writing some functions that I can't do in my production database.

Instead, I used the CASE statement:

`SELECT col_a, col_b, CASE 
        WHEN browser_string LIKE '%MSIE 7.%' THEN 'IE7' 
        WHEN browser_string LIKE '%MSIE 8.%' THEN 'IE8' 
        WHEN browser_string LIKE '%MSIE 9.%' THEN 'IE9' 
        WHEN browser_string LIKE '%MSIE 10.%' THEN 'IE10' 
        WHEN browser_string LIKE '%MSIE ' THEN 'IExx' 
        WHEN browser_string LIKE '%Firefox/%' THEN 'Firefox' 
        WHEN browser_string LIKE '%Chrome/%' THEN 'Chrome' 
        WHEN browser_string LIKE '%Safari/%' THEN 'Safari' 
        WHEN browser_string LIKE '%bingbot%' THEN 'bingbot' 
        WHEN browser_string LIKE '%ooglebot%' THEN 'googlebot' 
        WHEN browser_string LIKE '%bot%' THEN 'otherbot' 
        WHEN browser_string LIKE '%Bot%' THEN 'otherbot' 
        ELSE 'unknown' END AS browser
    FROM ...`

This by no means efficient as the report seems to take ages to run, but it does what I needed (after extending the when stuff a bit more).

Answer (score 0):

You are right. At least you should install something like mentioned here

https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/clr-assembly-regex-functions-for-sql-server-by-example/

to get some regexp functionality.

IMHO it is not understandable that regexps are not yet natively supported by SQLServer. As far as I know not even in SQLServer 2012.